# Best way to store pandas df data for recall in analysis

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large df in pandas that has a company's product information. Here is a small sample of rows with only the columns I believe are needed to get the information I desire.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Customers': [1,2,3,4,5,6]*3,
                   'Product':['Beer1','Beer2','Beer1','Beer4', 'Beer3', 'Beer5']*3,
                   'Packaging':['6pk','keg','big_keg','12pack','22 oz bottle','18pack']*3,
                   'Sale_Price':[25,50,75,34,54,99]*3}
                 )
```

I want to be able to pull the sale price:

```
def get_price(Customer, Product, Packaging): 
      abc = df[(df['Customers'] == Customer) & (df['Product'] == Product) & (df['Packaging'] == Packaging)]
      price = abc.iloc[0]['Sale_Price']
      return price
```

The function I wrote works for getting one value, but I was wondering if there is a better way to get and store pricing information for an entity's products for later use

Since I am usually using the prices as inputs in a multiplication formula using the examples below

Beer1 Run1: 365 12 packs, 43 big_kegs, 12 kegs 
Beer2 Run1: 400 18 packs, 67 kegs

So Ex1 would look something like this: Revenue = (365 * 12 pack price + 43 * big_keg price + 12 * keg price)

My Question(s):
 How to alter the function above to account for the examples? 
 How best to store all prices for later use?

More direct question based on comment: 
I have three arguments (maybe more due to additional pack type possibilities): Customer name, Product Name, Packaging Type, (additional pack type)

I need the sale price, prices for multiple pack types.

So, I have these Beer1, Customer2, 12pack, big_keg: How would my function handle this?
 Is a function the best way or should I create and store a master pricing dictionary or another storage method?

Will probably need a weighted average at some point, but one question at time.

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: What is the output you are trying to get? The revenue? And what do you mean store prices. You want prices for each type of beer?

Answer (score -1):

If what you are looking for is the total revenue each packaging type is bringing, you can simply do groupby.

`df.groupby('Packaging')['Sale_Price'].sum()`

output:

```
Packaging
12pack          102
18pack          297
22 oz bottle    162
6pk              75
big_keg         225
keg             150
Name: Sale_Price, dtype: int64
```

You can do the same for price info with unique function

`df.groupby('Packaging')['Sale_Price'].unique()`

```
Packaging
12pack          [34]
18pack          [99]
22 oz bottle    [54]
6pk             [25]
big_keg         [75]
keg             [50]
Name: Sale_Price, dtype: object
```

Which also help in checking if each type of packaging had one unique pricing or different sale price in the dataframe.

Comment: I am not looking for the total revenues by packaging type. It is more like writing my own software that allows me to get a review of a particular product/Beer Run. So I want to be able to pinpoint an analysis of a beer run and its associated sales, which includes how it was packaged, to whom it was sold, and in what quantities. More like a scalpel than an overall review.

Comment: I don't understand the exact output desired. The example function provided in the question retrieves exactly one related data point from sale_price column if such exist given the condition. It might be easier if you can provide a sample table of desired output?